# Is there any way to just change pdf title / tab title (Meta Data) of existing pdf in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, origami

I want to change pdf header title or tab browser title of existing pdf whenever open the pdf file but could not find way to do that can anyone help me in this regard? will be appreciated?

thanks in advance

I want a way to modify existing pdf title/header name in rails

[Click here to see pdf image header sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFyQI.png)

Comment: Please feel free to update your previous post with the desire by clicking the Edit button

Comment: @KJ I am using Carrierwave gem for uploading different pdf , the gem itself maintain every internal structure but i could not find any attribute title or any thing in respective gem which change the existing title of pdf